# Set properties for temp print file

Tags: php, javascript, openlayers

Having a bit of a problem setting the properties for a temporary file that is created to be printed later by the user.

To get into the details of the flow:

1. Customer presses a "Print Map Area" button in the site.
2. Menu comes up asking preferred dimensions (e.g. A4 Vertical, A4 Horizontal, A3 Vertical..etc)
3. The customer chooses one and temp file is created with these dimensions and shown in a new window for the customer to print to page from browser.

**NOTE: I am not trying to nor do I wish to attempt to change the customer's browser print settings, These settings are to create a temp file to help the user when the actual print to paper(or PDF) is done, actual printing is done manually by the user.**

I am currently using the OpenLayers 'tile stiching' print function, while this does half of what I am trying to achieve it does not address the other issues like page size and direction, and just prints the full screen.

Have been searching online for a solution to this that relates to the OpenLayers 'tile stitching' print function but have not been able to find anything useful(or anything for that matter).

If you know a way I can do this while still using the 'tile stitching' or another way to implement this would be greatly appreciated. The code I am using for this print function can be found at http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Printing.

Thanks would appreciate any help. If there is any part of this you feel is hard to understand would be happy to elaborate further.

**Further Information:**
I was able to get A4Vertical and A4Horizontal by using two functions. The problem now is that I can't just change the tile size for A3 as I want the print boundaries the same but just fitting on a larger paper size.

Answer (score 0):

I was [made aware](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17941/how-to-generate-a-thumbnail-of-an-openlayers-map) of a new feature in the development version of openlayers which will allow you to export your map as an image (take a snapshot).

Take a look at [this demo](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html). After you've generated the image you can allow the user to print it, save it, share it, etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply...the demo didn't seem to work though.. has it been taken off?

Comment: @Yus : Try again, it works for me. Give it a while to load. If you still have problems, let me know i'll copy/paste it to another server.

Comment: I waited for it finish loading but the map doesn't load and when I click the "export map" button I get a "exportmapcontrol is undefined"

Comment: I got it, it only seems to work on IE9 (I was viewing in firefox and it was loading in quirks mode on IE, so I had to manually change the doc type to IE9). Is it possible to set the page dimensions with this control?

Comment: No, this control has nothing to do with page dimensions. It is to export a map as an image. It helps for printing purposes, but has nothing to do with it directly.